# How to structure code with an animation on part of the view

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to make an iPad app with multiple "forms" that must be filled out. The view has a header and a footer section that are the same on all views. The middle part contains the form fields. I would like the animation between the pages to be only on the middle part. That is: The header and footer must stay in the view while the middle part slides to the next form.

I can create this easily in code, where I configure all fields that must be inserted in the code and then create the animation. However, this feels wrong and not very maintainable. Therefore, I would like to use the story board to configure each of the form pages. The question is: How do I do this? Do I need one or several View Controllers? How do I best create the views and organize the code?

PS. I work on an iOS 5.0 app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found out to do this is to create the views in xib-files. Then the view that should be shown next can be generated from the xib-file. All is done in one view controller (since a new view controller would take over the entire screen). This is easily maintainable and easy to animate.